# is bigquery the right choice?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I've a table on google spreadsheet, which needs to analyzed..

I had a look at big-query and it seems like what i need..

I'm still in a testing phase so my table is pretty dam small.. since my table is just 40x10 i am wondering if its a bit of an overkill..

But i do need the results immediately and it runs every minute for roughly 7 to 8 hours per day .. 5 days a week..

Also Google says first 100gb processed is free.

I will be staying well within my limits even with billing enabled right?? I don't want to be billed 4k$ like some of the people have faced... so wanted to understand how this works..

For a table of 40x10.. 
max 10 queries for the one table(per minute).. 
7 hours a day.. 
5 days a week..

I'll stay well within my limits right?? And yes am using apps script (for now) to get this up and running..

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [ScriptDB](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/script-db/) since your db is really small.

A short example of how it works (with an inbox example):

```
function checkMessages(name) {
var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
var msgs = db.query({table: "messages", IDto: name, statusreceiving: db.not("read")});
var infoMessages = [];
var messagesCount = msgs.getSize();
var stateMessages = false;
var idMessages = [];

while (msgs.hasNext()) {
var me = msgs.next();
  idMessages.push(me.messageID);
  me.statusreceiving = "received";
  db.save(me);
  }
if (messagesCount>0) {
stateMessages = true;
}
infoMessages.push(stateMessages,messagesCount,idMessages);
return infoMessages;
}
```

Comment: I realize for basic operations scriptDb is more than sufficient, but I require sorting and filtering of rows, maybe up to 5 times till I get my desired result. I highly doubt scriptDB will be able to handle all this. Also, I need really fast results.

Comment: scriptDB surely is fast. Also, for sorting you can use something like: var team = db.query({table: "availableTeam"}).sortBy("teamID") and for filtering you have db.query syntax above. For what you need, scriptDB is the right choice.

Comment: If it works as your say, it will help me out a lot to get a min version up and running. Will certainly give it a try and get back to you on that sir.
But just for my knowledge, will I go beyond my free big-query quota?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, BigQuery is probably not appropriate for your use case.

First, BigQuery cannot query directly over data in a Google spreadsheet.

Second, BigQuery is optimized and intended for querying massive amounts of data, so using it to query a 40x10 table is not ideal in terms of speed or efficiency.

Third, each query is billed for a minimum of 1 MB of data, regardless of how small your table is (see pricing details [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing)). At 10 queries per minute, 8 hours per day, 5 days per week, you'll hit just about exactly 100 GB of data in a 30-day month, and may very well go over your free quota now and then.

If you're just running one query that doesn't need to change very often, coding it up directly in AppsScript seems like a reasonable approach.